# Preserving negative/reverse string selection after updating TMemo text in Delphi?

Tags: delphi

In Delphi I'm having trouble preserving the `SelStart` and `SelLength` in a Memo that updates it text every 5 seconds when the selection is negative/reverse.

With negative/reverse selection I mean that I have started the selection somewhere and while holding shift pressed the left arrow key some times.

Code:

```
var
  caret: TPoint;
  sel_start, sel_length: Integer;
begin
  sel_start := Memo1.SelStart;    //          =  5
  sel_length := Memo1.SelLength;  //          = 10
  caret := Memo1.CaretPos;        // caret.x  = 15

  //'adi and bl' selected
  caret.x := sel_start;
  Memo1.Lines.Clear;
  Memo1.Lines.Add('laditadi and blah blah');
  Memo1.SelStart := sel_start;
  Memo1.SelLength := sel_length;

  Memo1.CaretPos := caret;
end;
```

The thing is that setting the SelLength seems to actually move the caret. And setting the caret after setting `SelLength` makes `SelLength := 0;`. Since the text keeps changing I can't use `TMemo.SelText` / `TMemo.SetSelText` before and after.

I can't find a way to preserve the caret pos...any clues?

Comment: The code in the question doesn't preserve selection for any selection. You need to set the caret before the selection. However, there's something fundamentally wrong with a control that allows both you and the timer to write to it.

Comment: FWIW: When I execute `SendMessage(Memo1.Handle, EM_GETSEL, WPARAM(@dwStart), LPARAM(@dwEnd));` with `var dwStart, dwEnd: DWORD;` under Windows 8/D2007 I get `dwStart < dwEnd` for selections in both directions.

Answer (score 2):

If sel_start has the same value as characterposition of the Caret, selection will be reversed by setting selstart to selstart+sellength and setting sellength to -sellength.

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  caret: TPoint;
  sel_start, sel_length,CharFromPos: Integer;
begin
  Memo1.SetFocus;
  GetCaretPos(Caret);
  CharFromPos := SendMessage(Memo1.Handle, EM_CHARFROMPOS, 0 ,Caret.Y*$FFFF + Caret.X) AND $FFFF;
  sel_start := Memo1.SelStart;    //          =  5
  sel_length := Memo1.SelLength;  //          = 10

  Memo1.Lines.Clear;
  Memo1.Lines.Add('laditadi and blah blah'#13#10'laditadi and blah blah');
  if  sel_start<>CharFromPos then
      begin
       Memo1.SelStart := sel_start;
       Memo1.SelLength := sel_length;
      end
    else
      begin
       Memo1.SelStart := sel_start + sel_length;
       Memo1.SelLength := - sel_length;
      end;

end;
procedure TForm1.Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
var
 p:Tpoint;
 b:Boolean;
 CharFromPos:Integer;
begin
   b := GetCaretPos(p);
   CharFromPos := SendMessage(Memo1.Handle, EM_CHARFROMPOS, 0 ,p.Y*$FFFF + p.X) AND $FFFF;
   Caption := Format('SelStart %d CharFromPos %d',[Memo1.SelStart,CharFromPos])
end;
```